# Filter only parameters that are present in the request

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

There are lots of articles that are about Java 8 lambda operations however I couldn't find what I need until now. I tried to convert them to my approach unfortunately I couldn't succeed

Imagine that you have request that comes in POJO such as ;

```
public class DummyRequest {

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String country;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country= country;
    }

}
```

During REST/SOAP request ***surname*** variable will be assigned as ***null***.

```
List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(
                new Person("maria", "gambert", "italy"),
                new Person("jack", "johson", "usa"),
                new Person("johnson", "jack", "usa"),
                new Person("kate", "julia", "spain"),
                new Person("jack","bob","uk");

DummyRequest dr = new DummyRequest();
dr.setName("jack");
dr.setCountry("usa");
```

If I knew in advance that the `surname` field would be `null`, I could manage to filter the list like this, ignoring that field:

```
List<Person> result4 = persons.stream().
filter(x -> dummyRequest.getName().equals(x.getName())).
filter( x-> dummyRequest.getCountry().equals(x.getCountry())).
collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However I don't know which fields will be `null` and which will not. How could I instead filter my data according to non-null request parameters only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter only by the non-null properties of `dummyRequest`, you can simply add a null check to each `Predicate`:

```
List<Person> result4 =
    persons.stream()
           .filter(x -> dummyRequest.getSurname() == null || dummyRequest.getSurname().equals(x.getSurname()))
           .filter(x -> dummyRequest.getName() == null || dummyRequest.getName().equals(x.getName()))
           .filter(x -> dummyRequest.getCountry() == null || dummyRequest.getCountry().equals(x.getCountry()))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

I would define a static method for that, since you are duplicating the code so many times:

```
private static boolean nullableOrEqual(String left, String right) {
    return left == null || left.equals(right);
}
```

And then the usage would be:

```
List<Person> result = persons.stream()
            .filter(x -> nullableOrEqual(dr.getSurname(), x.getSurname()))
            .filter(x -> nullableOrEqual(dr.getCountry(), x.getCountry()))
            .filter(x -> nullableOrEqual(dr.getName(), x.getName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: The presence of the unnecessarily boxed `Boolean.TRUE` indicates that you might have far more complex thoughts when you wrote `left == null ? Boolean.TRUE : left.equals(right)`, however, the result is an expression that can be simplified to `left == null || left.equals(right)`

Comment: @Holger so you are into mind reading now :) I wanted indeed to write something else that did not work in the end for me, you are quite right

Answer (score 3):

If you want to only apply the filter for which the `dummyRequest` contains a non-null value, you would have to dynamically build your stream for the most efficient solution.

This could easily be done by implementing a helper method that conditionally applies a filter:

```
public static <T, V> Stream<T> filterIfNotNull(Stream<T> stream, V filterValue, Function<T, V> property) {
    if (filterValue == null) {
        return stream;
    }

    return stream.filter(t -> filterValue.equals(property.apply(t)));
}
```

(in your example `T` would always be `Person` and `V` would always be `String`, but this generic version allows more reusability without additional complexity at the call site)

Then the stream/collect can be implemented like this:

```
Stream<Person> personStream = persons.stream();
personStream = filterIfNotNull(personStream, dummyRequest.getName(), Person::getName);
personStream = filterIfNotNull(personStream, dummyRequest.getSurname(), Person::getSurname);
personStream = filterIfNotNull(personStream, dummyRequest.getCountry(), Person::getCountry);
List<Person> result4 = personStream.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This technique guarantees that the null-check on the request's properties is only applied once.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `checkNonNullProperties` helper method that returns a `Predicate<Person>` that only checks for equality of non-null properties of your `DummyRequest` instance. You could use it as follows:

```
Predicate<Person> condition = checkNonNullProperties(
    Arrays.asList(
        dr.getCountry(),
        dr.getName(),
        dr.getSurname()),
    Arrays.asList(
        Person::getCountry,
        Person::getName,
        Person::getSurname));

List<Person> result = people.stream()
    .filter(condition)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The helper method:

```
private static <T> Predicate<T> checkNonNullProperties(
        List<?> values,
        List<Function<T, ?>> extractors) {
    return IntStream.range(0, values.size()).mapToObj(i ->
            (Predicate<T>) t -> {
                Object value = values.get(i);
                Object property = extractors.get(i).apply(t);
                return value == null || value.equals(property);
            })
            .reduce(t -> true, Predicate::and);
}
```

The `checkNonNullProperties` method receives a list of values to check for equality and a list of functions that will extract the properties from the argument of the returned predicate. The extracted properties will be checked for equality against their corresponding values only for those values that are non-null.

I'm using an `IntStream` to drive iteration over both lists. In the `mapToObj` method I'm mapping the stream's `int` value to a predicate that returns `true` when the provided value is `null` or when it's equal to the extracted property.

In the end, these predicates are reduced to a final predicate via the `Predicate::and` operator. In the `reduce` call, I'm providing the identity predicate for the `AND` operator, which is `t -> true` (always returns true).